# How should I set up UITableViewCell subclasses with UIControls in them?

Tags: ios, uitableview, subclass

I have a dynamically generated UITableView (so I have to use prototype cells, not static cells) with many cells on it.  Each cell will have a UILabel on it.  Additionally, each cell will also have at least one UIControl (as of right now, it could be a UITextfield or a UISegmentedControl, but I want to keep it flexible in case I add something else in the future).

The user is going to go through and set all the controls to the state they want, then press a "Calculate" button at the end.  On the click of that button, I'm going to need to be able to get information about what the user did with each control (what text the user has entered into each textfield, which segement they have selected in each control, etc.).

What would be the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting these values from the model object that populates the table, not from the table itself. It's hard to know how you should do this without knowing more about your data source, and what values you need when the user clicks a button -- do you need values from all the rows? From just the row whose cell has the label cellLabel (if so, how do you know which cellLabel to pass to the method)?

How much it can be cleaned up depends to a great extent on the structure of your data.

Comment: Ah, yes, I understand what you mean.  The data source is itself a little messy, but I think this is definitely on the right track.  I'll have to look into this closer to be sure it will work for me, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I have several UICell subclasses, one for each combination I've needed so far (so I have a LabelTextboxCell, LabelSegmentCell, LabelSegmentTextboxCell, LabelTextTextCell, etc.).  When I do the call to get the information for that cell, the code in my call looks like:

```
-(NSString *) getValueFor:(NSString *)cellLabel fromControl:(NSInteger *)controlCount inTable:(UITableView *)table
{
    if ([cellLabel isEqualToString:@"Label1"] || [cellLabel isEqualToString:@"Label3"])
    {
        for (LabelTextboxSegmentCell *cell in table.visibleCells)
        {
             if ([cell.label.text isEqualToString:cellLabel])
             {
                 if (controlCount == 1)
                 {
                     return cell.textfield.text;
                 }
                 else if (controlCount == 2)
                 {
                     return [cell.segment titleForSegmentAtIndex:[cell.segment selectedSegmentIndex]];
                 }
             }
             //else {continue - this is not the cell I want)
         }
    }
    else if ([cellLabel isEqualToString:@"Label2"])
    {
        //...same for loop structure and such as before except specific to LabelTextTextCell
    }
    //.... couple more else ifs and their loops
}
```

This is terrible.  It works, but it is messy, prone to errors, very hard to add to in the future, and totally against best practice.  But it's the best I've come up with so far.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: How are you calling this method? Is it response to changing one of the values in one of the controls?

Comment: @rdelmar: No, It's called when the user clicks a button to perform some calculations that are based on the state of the controls.  I track user interaction with the controls elsewhere, that is equally confusing and messy, so if there was a way to clean up both at the same time that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The cells come and go dynamically in a tableView. It'll drive you crazy using them to store values. I suggest using a mutable array to store data and to supply the cells with what they need.

Here's a solution in 3 simple steps.

1, subclass one UITableCell and use it for all of your prototype cells. All you have to do in the cell subclass is set all the properties that ANY of the elements in your cells (and synthesize them in the .m file)

2, in the IB, set the class for all of your cells as that UITableCell subclass you just made, and here's the crucial part, in IB, control-drag from the cell to whatever elements (in that cell) you want to link to. This is imperative for step three to work.

3, in your UITableViewController, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, use your cell subclass and tag anything you want in it with the index of the tableView (which you get in that method call for a cell).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellOneID = @"CellOne";
    MySubclassTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textFieldOne.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.textFieldOne.delegate = self;

    cell.labelTwo.text = [myMutableArray objectForIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.labelTwo.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
```

You can change the label text by changing the corresponding object in the array and then calling:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Then, when your textField calls to say stuff is happening to it, you can check it's tag and know which one it is. (of course by implementing the UITextField delegate methods in the VC)

Comment: I see. Note in my code the delegate for textFieldOne is set to self. If you have that, you can add the delegate method: textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField or related methods to your VC. And that's where you get notified that the text field has been edited, check the tag and pull the current text. Remember, anything in those cells is impermanent so it's best to catch the data as it's being entered and store it elsewhere, then feed it back in as the cell is being re-created during scrolling. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I have an object that I'm storing all the user choices in, and I'm now checking against what's in that object instead of looking at the table itself.